# converting list of lists into a table

Tags: python

I have this list of lists:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

that i have to transform into this table:

```
apples      Alice    dogs
oranges       Bob    cats 
cherries    Carol    moose 
banana      David    goose
```

The trick for me, is have the "lines" to be converted into columns (i.e. apples, oranges, cherries, banana under same column)

I have tried different options (A):

```
for row in tableData:
        output = [row[0].ljust(20)]
            for col in row[1:]:
             output.append(col.rjust(10))
            print(' '.join(output))
```

option (B):

## method 2

```
for i in tableData:
    print( i[0].ljust(10)+(str(i[1].ljust(15)))+(str(i[2].ljust(15)))+
    (str(i[3].ljust(15))))
```

None seems to address the issue.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this Py2 or Py3? `print` differs from one to the other, and the way your example code uses it doesn't exercise any of the differences to make that clear.

Comment: Also: [Python: Printing Lists as Tabular Data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9535954/216074)

Comment: this is python 3.5

Answer (score 8):

To transpose the table, use the zip-and-splat trick.

To left-or-right-justify cells, use the [format spec language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> for row in zip(*tableData):
...     print '{:<10}{:>7}    {:<10}'.format(*row)
...     
apples      Alice    dogs      
oranges       Bob    cats      
cherries    Carol    moose     
banana      David    goose
```

Comment: No need for explicit field width on the final entry, since it's left justified and will spill if it exceeds the width anyway. Otherwise, yeah, best answer.

Comment: thank you. what exactly do these #'s represent

Comment: Did you follow the link? The numbers are the space that is reserved for the content so that left-or-right-justify knows how many spacess have to be added on the left or right side.

Answer (score 2):

One could also play around with [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
In [22]: import pandas as pd
In [22]: pd.DataFrame(tableData).T # .T means transpose the dataframe
Out[22]:
          0      1      2
0    apples  Alice   dogs
1   oranges    Bob   cats
2  cherries  Carol  moose
3    banana  David  goose
```

---

Remove those *annoying* numbers by setting columns and indices to blank:

```
In [27]: l1, l2 = len(tableData), len(tableData[0])

In [28]: pd.DataFrame(tableData, index=['']*l1, columns=['']*l2).T
Out[28]:

    apples  Alice   dogs
   oranges    Bob   cats
  cherries  Carol  moose
    banana  David  goose
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but I think whipping out `pandas` for a simple problem might be overdoing it, just a bit. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I did considered that, but on a second thought I think  it's a tool worth considering by the questioner (if not now, in the long run) :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to "flip" the nested list is to use `zip`:

```
for fruit, name, animal in zip(*tableData):
    print(fruit.ljust(10), name.ljust(10), animal.ljust(10))
```

This prints:

```
apples     Alice      dogs
oranges    Bob        cats
cherries   Carol      moose
banana     David      goose
```

Comment: amazing!!!. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is already a builtin function for this: `zip`.

```
zip(* [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
       ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
       ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']])
```